# PHP does nothing if username/email is wrong

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm making a login system. Everything works, but when i use a email (username) in the login that is not in the database it will go to the URL with filename and then just the form data (email and password). I need to set the header with an error so i can say that login was failed. Does anyone see the problem?

```
<?php

ob_start();

if (isset($_REQUEST['password'])) {
    require 'connect.php';
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $mail = $_REQUEST['email'];

    if (empty($mail) || empty($password)) {
        header('location: ../login.php?error=empty');
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = ?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../login.php?error=sqlError");
            exit();
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $mail);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $passwordCheck = password_verify($password, $row['wachtwoord']);
                if ($passwordCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../login.php?error=passwordWrong");
                    exit();
                } elseif ($passwordCheck == true) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['account_id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['gebruikersnaam'];
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=succes");
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                header("Location login.php?error=noUser");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../login.php?error=");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You have a typo, a missing colon in `header("Location login.php?error=noUser");`. Should be `Location:`.

Comment: Probably an oversight from the [previous repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107377/header-is-not-set-in-php). Now, apart from creating a new account and the code regressions, what other debugging steps have you taken?

Answer (score 0):

Since your login form is working.
Let me ask you:

Is Your form action using get method or post method?.

**Remember when you send a form with GET method to backend eg to a php file, all the form parameters are seen in the url okay.**

So You can check this below.

1.) Ensure that your form is using Post method eg method="POST"

2). Why are you using `$_REQUEST[..]`. in php
its better you used `$_POST` method for http request coming from form inputs

Something like

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
require 'connect.php';
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
```

OR

```
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    require 'connect.php';
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
```

**Note:**  The variables in `$_REQUEST` are provided to the script via the **GET, POST, and COOKIE** input mechanisms and
 therefore could be modified by the remote user and cannot be trusted. Therefore proper validation and sanitization should be
done on both front and backend.

[see php manual warnings](http://%20http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Finally,
If any of this suggestion does not work for you, you can then upload also all your form fields and I will get it working for you. Thank You